# Ruby how to get 2018-08-25 from DateTime object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a DateTime property on one of my model objects.

Example data: `"2018-08-28T01:00:00.000+00:00"`

I am creating a new JSON object based of the DateTime property, but I just want to put this part into it `2018-08-28`

I also want to grab the hour part and put it into the JSON object also. For example `01`

Currently what I have is this JSON passed over.

```
{"date":"2018-08-25T18:00:00.000+00:00"}
```

I want this

```
{"date":"2018-08-25", "hour":"01"}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parse the string into the valid `DateTime` instance and then print it back in any format you need with [`DateTime#strftime`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Time.html#method-i-strftime):

```
require 'datetime'
DateTime.
  iso8601("2018-08-28T01:00:00.000+00:00").
  strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
#⇒ "2018-08-28"
```

To get both a date and an hour one might do:

```
date, hour =
  DateTime.
    iso8601("2018-08-28T01:00:00.000+00:00").
    strftime('%Y-%m-%d,%H').
    split(',')
#⇒ ["2018-08-28", "01"]
```

To get a desired hash:

```
%w|date hour|.
  zip(
    DateTime.
      iso8601("2018-08-28T01:00:00.000+00:00").
      strftime('%Y-%m-%d,%H').
      split(',')
  ).
  to_h
#⇒ {
#    "date" => "2018-08-28",
#    "hour" => "01"
# }
```